# MakeQueryTable_management

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, query, table

When I run this code, it says "An invalid SQL statement was used". Any idea what does it mean?

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace ="C:/RG/Projects/CriticalDataNetwork/CDEC.gdb"

try:
    inTable = "Avg_Daily"
    keyField = "STATION_ID"
    inField = [["Avg_Daily.OBJECTID","OBJECTID",],["Avg_Daily.STATION_ID","STATION_ID"],   ["Avg_Daily.DLY_AVG", "DLY_AVG"]]
    whereClause = "\"STATION_ID\" = 'CAP', 'DDM'"
    outTable = "Test"
    print outTable

    arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(inTable,  outTable, "USE_KEY_FIELDS", keyField, inField, whereClause)

except Exception, e:
    # If an error occurred, print line number and error message
    import traceback, sys
    tb = sys.exc_info()[2]
    print "Line %i" % tb.tb_lineno
    print e.message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot use equal with more than one value

use either in or OR to do this

```
"\"STATION_ID\" IN ('CAP', 'DDM')"

"\"STATION_ID\" = 'CAP' OR \"STATION_ID\" = 'DDM'"
```

note that I recommand using """ to clarify your strings

""" "STATION_ID" IN ('CAP', 'DDM') """